# mySQL combine WHERE IN (?,?,?,..) clause with %?%

Tags: php, mysqli

How make a query who combine WHERE IN (?,?,?,..) clause and %?% (that is usually use with LIKE operator) in stmt query ?

In the following code I try to do a query like it:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `name` IN (%?%, %?%, %?% )
```

MySQL table (items):

```
================
|     name     |  
================
| google pixel | 
----------------
| iphone 9, iphone 10, iphone 11  | 
----------------
| windows phone |
```

PHP :

```
$array = array("pixel" => 1, "iphone 10" => 2);
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($array), '?');

$keys = $values = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = "%".$key."%";                                             //<- here
    $values[] = !empty($value) ? $value : null;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `name` IN (".implode(',', $placeholders).")";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

call_user_func_array(
     array($stmt, 'bind_param'), 
     array_merge(
         array(str_repeat('s', count($keys))),
         $keys
     )
 );

 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
 $stmt->close();

 while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     $items[$row['name']] = $row;
 }    
 $result->free();

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($items);echo"</pre>";
```

Comment: PHP is not my forte, but the pattern you should be following is to bind e.g. `%val_to_search%` directly to the wildcard placeholder.  The `%` should not appear in the statement.

Comment: `IN` will only match the actual values, you will probably need to do something like `name LIKE ? OR name like ?` with the ? bound with `%value%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from Nigel works. I change the query by :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `name` LIKE ".implode(' OR `name` LIKE ', $placeholders);
```